# JavaScript critical error at line 120, column 85 in http://localhost:50754/page.aspx SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, plsql

I have a following code in visual basic. When I call it on a button click event I get the error 'SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant'. Can I use PL/SQL like this from vb code:

```
  strInsert = "DECLARE "
  strInsert = strInsert + " in_xml_value varchar2(32767) "
  strInsert = strInsert + " BEGIN "
  strInsert = strInsert + " in_xml_value := "
  strInsert = strInsert + " '" + dv1.Table.Rows(j).Item("XML_Report")
  strInsert = strInsert + "' " + "INSERT into Report (ID,USER, XML_Report)"
  strInsert = strInsert + " VALUES(" + CStr(dv1.Table.Rows(j).Item("ID"))
  strInsert = strInsert + ", '" + dv1.Table.Rows(j).Item("USER")
  strInsert = strInsert + "', XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(in_xml_value)" + ");"
  strInsert = strInsert + " commit; "
  strInsert = strInsert + " END; "
  clsREPORTS.strInsert = New SqlTypes.SqlString(strInsert)
```

When debug I get this error:

```
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 40:

 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

 := ; not null default character

 The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

 ORA-06550: line 1, column 4078:

 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:

 * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem

 <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2

 like4 likec between || multiset memb
```

Comment: Which one is line 120??

Comment: I have edited the question with the error which I got while I was debugging.

Comment: Hmmh, I sadly don't know anything about SQL so I cannot help you further here...

Comment: Thank you anyway for your interest in my problem.

Comment: I added the 'sql' tag to your question. It might help you get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strInsert = strInsert + " in_xml_value varchar2(32767) "
```

This should be with semicolon at the end. So it becomes :

`strInsert = strInsert + " in_xml_value varchar2(32767) ;"`

Also every statement should end with semicolon so you need to have one before your `INSERT` too.

Comment: Great. That was the problem. Thank you.